# Communicate with SignalR server application from another Windows process

Tags: asp.net-core, delphi, iis, signalr

I have followed [the guide from Microsoft for getting started with SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). This worked perfectly, and I was able to publish and deploy the application to IIS.

Now I need to communicate with the .NET application from another Windows process (specifically a Delphi program). What I want to do is to tell the .NET application to send SignalR message (i.e. invoke a method on all connected clients).

How can I accomplish this?

I'm not sure how the .NET application is being executed - does it have its own Windows process that I could send Windows messages to? Or would it be easier to send a local HTTP GET/POST request from the Delphi program to localhost? If so, how can I make the SignalR application handle it?

Comment: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/how-to-create-real-time-applications-with-signalr-on-windows/

Comment: @LexLi Know of any free-for-commercial-use Delphi components? And a guide on how to get a Delphi program working with IIS?

Comment: The SignalR protocol itself is not difficult to implement, and you can find many open source implementations (JavaScript for instance) to get started, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/docs/specs/HubProtocol.md If others decide to keep their Delphi SignalR client closed source and you don't want to buy, it's likely that you need to write your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a controller and inject the `IHubContext<ChatHub>`. Use the hub context to send message to clients.

```
public class MessageController : Controller 
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;

    public MessageController(IHubContext<MessageHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage([FromForm] string message)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Then call this endpoint from your delphi app.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! Just want to add for all .NET newbies like myself who might find this in the future, that you have to create the directory `<Project root>/Controllers`, right click on it and use `Add->Controller` to add `MessageController.cs`, which is where the above code goes. Also, in `Program.cs` you have to add `app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "message",
    pattern: "message/{action=Index}/{data?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Message" }
);` and then you can use the URL `/message/SendMessage` to send a POST request to the controller method.